# Internet Explorer shows file download security warning - JSP page

Tags: java, internet-explorer, jsp

I am haiving a website developed using JSP and Java.I have my login using servlet.Everything works perfectly in firefox.But i got some unsual error like downloading window in IE 8.What will be the issue.?

My screen shot image of what i am getting in IE.[image: Screen shot -IE8]

Comment: I got my issue fixed by just removing the pageencoding:

    `<%@page pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>` .Is this a proper solution?

Answer (score 0):

I got my issue fixed by just removing the pageencoding:

```
<%@page pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
```

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: Also, when you click Open, do you get the JSP source code, or the page as expected?

Comment: When i click open , i am getting my jsp page opening in a notepad.